# Do I need to load from memory a base address of an array to a temporary register in this MIPS code?

Tags: arrays, mips, mips32

I'm working on Homework and I have to translate some c code 
into MIPS(32-bit).

I can use 3 registers `$s0` for a variable `x`, '$s1' for a variable `y`
and '$s3' for the base address of array 'A[]'.

My goal is to be able to perform some conditional `if` logic which compares a certain index of Array 'A' with variable 'y' ( in this case `A[x] < y`)

my code so far:

`sll $t0, $s0,2 # t0 = x *4`

`add $t0,$t0,$s3 # t0 = x*4 + &A[0] = A[x]`

My question is: does register $t0 already points to memory address of 'A[x]' hence I can move forward with what I have so far and start comparing values:

`slt $t1,$t0,$s1 # if A[x] < y then $t1 = 1`

or do I need to load the word from memory using the 'lw' pseudoinstruction at the beginning of my code:

`lw $t0, 0($s3) #temp reg $t0 gets A[0]`

`sll $t1, $s0,2 # t0 = x *4`

`add $t0,$t1,$t0 # t0 = x*4 + &A[0] = A[x]`

`rest of code goes here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $t0 will contain the memory location of where A[x] is stored.

"does register $t0 already points to memory address of 'A[x]' hence I can move forward with what I have so far and start comparing values:"

Yes, you are correct that $t0 points to memory address of 'A[x]'. But
you cannot compare yet because you have the address where A[x] is stored and NOT the value AT that address.  Therefore you need to perform a load word instruction.

"I need to load the word from memory using the 'lw' pseudoinstruction at the beginning of my code:"
You are correct that you need to load the word from memory.  Remember that $t0 has your address of interest that you want to load from memory. ($t0 = address of A[x])

You can do this:

```
lw $t0, 0($t0) # temp reg. $t0 gets A[x]
```

Then you can do the comparison.

Note:  Recall that registers are separate from memory.  In order to make comparisons with values from registers and values from memory, you need to use `lw` with the appropriate address to bring the value from memory into a particular register.

Comment: so, `lw $t0, 0($t0)` needs to be the first line of code ?

Comment: Not unless $t0 already contains your desired location.  It should be after `sll $t0, $s0,2 # t0 = x *4` and `add $t0,$t0,$s3 # t0 = x*4 + &A[0] = A[x]` but before your set less than instruction.